# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure [Kivy]

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, kivy, buildozer

In my app I am fetching JSON from various sites but I get handshake failure on a particular site. My app works fine on windows but fails on android. here is log snipet which I have doubt on. I guess there is some certificate issue.

```
    I/python  (16801):  /data/data/org.test.coinswatch/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:334: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

    I/python  (16801):  /data/data/org.test.coinswatch/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:132: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

    I/python  (16801): [ CoinsWatch ]except buyucoin [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

    I/python  (16801): [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
```

My Buildozer requirements are as follows:

```
requirements = kivy,requests[security],openssl
```

Need some direction to solve the issue.

Comment: You are using an outdated version of python. It does not support SNI and starts with an SSLv3 handshake. Using such an old version is a security vulnerability. Delete this version and never use it again!

Comment: Its true that python version has something to do with it but atleast I got response from the server on windows. Could you please tell me whats wrong with android?

Comment: Your Android python version only supports SSLv3 and old ciphers. The server on the other hand only supports TLS1.x. Therefore client and servers don't speak the same "language" and hence can't communicate. For SSL/TLS at least one version and one cipher must be present on client and server for establishing the communication channel.

Comment: If I am getting it correct, If I implement a TLS connection then it should work rite? just out of curiosity.

Comment: If you could just "implement TLS" there is the chance that it would work. However you can't just implement TLS. This would mean to replace the OpenSSL library that has been compiled into the python executable. Hence in the end you have to recompile python or use a newer existing version. Anyway I don't understand why someone would want to use Python on Android. Develop a real Android app and everything is fine.