# HTTPS Request in Kivy

Tags: android, python, ssl, kivy, aws-api-gateway

I've been struggling with HTTPS requests in a Kivy app tied to an API hosted through AWS API Gateway. First, I moved from Python3 to 2 and then from the requests library to kivy's URLRequest.

The app works fine on my linux desktop. When I made the API request with the requests library I got an SSL error: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I moved to using URLRequest, which seems to be having the same SSL error as requests was. Arguments passed into the URLRequest error callback are: (, SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:503: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'))

I found this stackoverflow question: [SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure [Kivy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597438/ssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure-kivy)

Which implies this has to do with outdated python versions.

Is it just a Kivy android app is incapable of communicating with an AWS API Gateway?

Buildozer .spec lines:
requirements = hostpython2, kivy, future, python-dateutil, openssl, pyopenssl, jmespath, botocore, boto3, requests

android.permissions = INTERNET

UPDATE: I tested a HTTPS GET request with the URL https://kivy.org/logos/kivy-logo-black-64.png. This completed successfully in the Android App. This problem seems to be specific to the SSL version used by AWS API Gateway

UPDATE2: Kivy on Android also works fine with Google Cloud Platform's cloud functions HTTPS endpoints. Even more evidence this issue is specifically tied to AWS API Gateway.

Comment: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html this post may help you debug further. I am seeing issues like wrong hostname or wrong port used (80 instead of 443). Try using your AWS url with `curl --sslv2`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .spec file has internet permissions. Also I believe you need 'hostpython2' in your requirements if you are using python2. Im not sure if any of the requirements you have in there are python 2 or 3 dependent but make sure they work for python 2 if that's what your using. Also I dont think you need the [security] in your requests requirement. Try just putting 'requests' also u might try installing sqlite and adding g that into your requirements as well.

Comment: I added hostpython2 to the requirements. I've updated the question to show the new requirements list. I had granted INTERNET permissions in the buildozer.spec (line also added to the question).

I tried adding sqlite but ran into some issues. Is sqlite likely to add something for SSL?

Comment: @noobiemcfoob was there any resolution? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @PetarLuketina: It seemed to be a problem specific to the HTTPS implementation in AWS. I was able to communicate over HTTPS with a Google Cloud Platform API.

Comment: @noobiemcfoob I actually figured it out last night too. I added one requirement to my `buildoze.spec` and it displayed the database in my app. I believe it was just adding `openssl` (I'll double check) along with `requests`, python, kivy, etc. which you already have. Nevertheless, I'm glad that you were able to figure it out!

Comment: @PetarLuketina: were you able to get this to work on an AWS API gateway endpoint? That would be great to hear

Comment: @noobiemcfoob hey. I just made a tutorial. Here's the github page to all the files: https://github.com/Petar-Luketina/Firebase-Sample . There's also a link to a YouTube video in the `README.md`. I hope it helps!